# Pygame Python 2.7 osx failures

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame

I've installed the **[quasiben 64 bit osx Pygame version using conda](https://anaconda.org/quasiben/pygame)**. I'm running **Python 2.7.1** and I've made sure the library was installed by doing :

```
$ conda search pygame
```

and getting the following :

```
pygame                    *  1.9.1                    py27_1  quasiben
```

Anyway when I try to import the library in one of my .py program, I get the following failures :

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/usrname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/usrname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/pygame/base.so
Reason: image not found
```

My system is *El Capitan*.

Comment: did u find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try just uninstalling pygame and reinstalling it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_TzqzKZpMw

And make sure your pygame version is up to date along with your python.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing one of the dependencies. Try to install all dependencies using **brew**:

```
brew install sdl sdl_ttf sdl_image sdl_mixer portmidi
```

[This article](http://www.srmathias.com/python-for-psychophysics-on-os-x-yosemite/) has nice instruction on how to install PyGame from scratch on OS X.

Comment: I ended up also re-installing of XQuartz(https://www.xquartz.org) before it finally fully worked for me.